# How to call forkJoin inside a another forkjoin?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a route resolver like this. I want to make two more HTTP requests based on the first response from the forkjoin. I was trying to add another forkjoin inside the first one or if there is a better way to handle this kind of situations. I am trying to combine both responses into one.

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<any> {
    const userDetails = this._spotify.getCurrentUser();
    const newReleases = this._spotify.getNewReleases();
    const recentPlayedTrack = this._spotify.getUserRecentlyPlayedTracks();
    const resolvedData = forkJoin([
        userDetails,
        newReleases,
        recentPlayedTrack
    ]).pipe(
        map((dashboardApiResults) => {
            const url = `...${dashboardApiResults[1].id}`;
            const options = {
                useUrlPrefix: false
            };
            const req1 = this._http.get(url, options);
            const req2 = this._http.get(url, options);
            const requests = forkJoin([req1, req2]);

            return {
                userDetails: dashboardApiResults[0],
                newReleases: dashboardApiResults[1],
                recentPlayedTracks: dashboardApiResults[2]
            };
        })
    );
    return resolvedData;
}
```

Comment: You should start by refactoring your code into clearly named utility methods. There is way too much going on in this method to reason about.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `any` wherever possible. It makes it even harder to write correct code

Comment: @Clashsoft, Can you check now, I am trying to combine both responses

Comment: How is the second forkJoin related to the first forkJoin? It seems that the second forkJoin is not using the response from the first.

Comment: @carlokid, my actual code is a mess so I have simplified it, from the first response I am getting some ids. With those id's I am trying to execute the second forkjoin.

Comment: nested forkjoins would be fine 
(keep in mind you may need to run catcherror on the api calls in them otherwise a fail will make the forkjoin as a whole fail)

But you don't seem to be even returning anything from that initial forkjoin (dashboardApiResults isn't part of the final return statement).

This also seems to be a place where a higher order operator is needed (switchmap/mergemap/etc) instead of just map.

Comment: Do you still need to return the result of the first forkJoin as the final return? or only the result of the second forkJoin?

Comment: @iamaword, It would be really helpful if you can share an example.

Comment: @carlokid, I need to combine them both like total of 5 results, first 3 second 2 responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my queries that you have answered, I think you can use "of" operator and return the combined results as Observable type.

```
map((dashboardApiResults) => {
     const url = `...${dashboardApiResults[1].id}`;
     const options = {
         useUrlPrefix: false
     };
     const req1 = this._http.get(url, options);
     const req2 = this._http.get(url, options);

     return forkJoin([req1, req2]).pipe(
         concatMap([res1, res2]) => {
             return of({
                userDetails: dashboardApiResults[0],
                newReleases: dashboardApiResults[1],
                recentPlayedTracks: dashboardApiResults[2],
                result1: res1,
                result2: res2
             });
         })
     );
})
```

Comment: I wonder if the initial map could be a concatMap to make it more concise

Comment: You really don't even need concatMap(), you could just use map(). Then you don't need of().

Comment: Also, is this example not returning `Observable<Observable<T>>`? The map is returning `forkJoin()` as its value.